# Total amount in words in qweb report odoo

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, openerp-8, odoo-9

I want to get `total amount` of `purchase order` in `words` on `qweb report`.
Someone please tell me what is the process to get it or what code i can do... 
i'll be very thankful...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a function in your `purshase.order` model that converts `total_amount` to letters.

```
from openerp import models, api
from openerp.tools import amount_to_text_fr

class purchase_order(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'purchase.order'

    @api.depends('amount_total', 'currency_id')
    def compute_text(self):
        return amount_to_text_fr(self.amount_total, self.currency_id.symbol)
```

To call it from QWEB reports use:

```
<span t-esc="o.compute_text()" />
```

Comment: Its giving me some other language. i want to get it in English  so please tell me what is happning

Comment: @TahirNoor I am glad to help.Change `fr` to `en`.